# Javascript timer is not working correctly / struggling with test cases

Tags: javascript, frontend

I am completing some self learning while in uni holidays and am attempting to make a timer for a freeCodeCamp project. I am failing two of the test cases for this (with the corresponding error messages):

13. When a session countdown reaches zero (NOTE: timer MUST reach 00:00), a new break countdown should begin, counting down from the value currently displayed in the id="break-length" element.

*Timer has switched to Break time, but it didn't start with the correct value.: expected 4 to equal 5
AssertionError: Timer has switched to Break time, but it didn't start with the correct value.: expected 4 to equal 5*

15. When a break countdown reaches zero (NOTE: timer MUST reach 00:00), a new session countdown should begin, counting down from the value currently displayed in the id="session-length" element.

*Timer has switched back to Session time, but it didn't start with the correct value.: expected 0 to equal 1
AssertionError: Timer has switched back to Session time, but it didn't start with the correct value.: expected 0 to equal 1*

I believe this issue is happening because in my code when updating the timeLeft after it reaches 0, and then recursively calling startTimer, the next time through it decrements timeLeft before displaytimeLeft() is called.

here is the code for the function that I am experiencing issues with.

```
function startTimer() {
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    timeLeft--;
    displayTimeLeft();

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      audio.play();
      clearInterval(intervalId);

      if (onBreak) {
        onBreak = false;
        timeLeft = sessionLengthValue * 60;
        document.getElementById("status-label").textContent = "Session";
      } else {
        onBreak = true;
        timeLeft = breakLengthValue * 60;
        document.getElementById("status-label").textContent = "Break";
      }
      startTimer();
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

here is the codepen link to my full code, with the test cases:

https://codepen.io/LiamJ009/pen/WNKjexB

I have tried various things, The most obvious is to call `displayTimeLeft` before decrementing so that rather than the display going from 00:00 -> 04:59 when starting a 5 minute break (and thus the assertion error 4 != 5), it would display 05:00 briefly and then decrement and reupdate.

However any time I try this it ends up leaving the timer in an endless loop and the test case never finishes.

I have tried making a conditional for when `timeLeft === 1` and reversing the order of updating the display and decrementing time but it again ends in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution after a good night's sleep. I edited the startTimer() function to include the following code:

`timeLeft += 1;`

I inserted this for when the timer reached 0, and so that the correct start time would be displayed and pass the test cases.